# MSO bugs/reqs tabs show wrong window title

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, title, homepage

Minor nitpick:

When on the homepage, browsing the `bugs` or `reqs` tab shows the same window title as the `featured` tab.

> Featured Questions - Meta Stack Overflow

I assume this should say "Bugs" or "Feature Requests", respectively.

I've only seen this on MSO, probably because the tabs in question don't exist on other sites. I don't know if any other sites use custom tabs for stuff like this, but it might be worth checking.

[image: a simple screenshot illustrating the issue at hand. yes, i know it's nice, thank you.]

Comment: Nice one ! Also +1 for the circles

Comment: @JoshC no this is a bug with meta homepage title, on certain conditions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd My bad - you're right. The title changes when clicking on hot questions.. It also does this on the main site too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this was pushed in an earlier build - tabs should have all the proper titles now.